# Creating a script to have a interactive checklist on a Google Site that saves locally

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a checklist for a Google site. I am able to code one that will check off, but will not save when the page is refreshed. Because I can't use the Java script for it, I wanted to create an apps script for the checklist to save locally. How do I do this from a google slide?

I have tried to create the apps script, but run into errors.

Comment: Why isn't javascript available to you? Can you write a webapp?

Comment: I tried JAVA in the site and it didn't work. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Where do I write a webapp? I am very amateur...

Comment: First of all let me just say that Java is a different language than Javascript

Comment: I write my webapps in the script editor of a spreadsheet most of the time

Comment: Google Slides can also be a script container

Comment: I know you can embed webapps into the new google sites because I just embedded one of mine.  And it gets all of it  data from spreadsheets.  It plays music that is saved on my google drive.  So I think that should work for you.